# How to load beans in inherited XML config, before beans in Configuration classes (integration tests in Spring)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, integration-testing

When writing integration tests in Spring, how can I ensure that all the beans in my parent context are loaded before any others?

Currently, the context classes further down my hierarchy are being loaded too early and it's causing null pointer exceptions.

- I am mixing XML and @Configuration classes

**My set up**

I have an abstract test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/persistence-context.xml"}) <-- My persistence layer contains my DAO classes
public abstract class MyBaseTest implements ApplicationContextAware { ... }
```

...and my actual tests are in a concrete class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
})
public class MyTest extends MyBaseTest { 
@Autowired
MyDao myDao; // when I debug my code, I can see that this does not stay null - it gets loaded eventually!

... 
}
```

... which needs beans from my TestConfig class

```
@Import(value = {AnotherConfigClass.class})
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

@Autowired
MyDAO myDAO; <-- this is null when loading classes


@Bean
public MyService myService() {
    MyService myService = new MyService();
    myService.setDAO(myDAO); <-- my DAO is null at this point!
    return myService;
}

...
```

}

... which needs beans from my AdditionalConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class AnotherConfigClass {

...

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    myService.doSomethingUsingMyDAO(); <--- I need to use myService here, but a NPE is thrown.
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, annotations on base classes are not inherited on concrete classes. You have to explicitely load `/persistence-context.xml`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/persistence-context.xml"}),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
})
public class MyTest extends MyBaseTest {
...
```